# Deploying an App Engine application using an archive file [jar/war]

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment, archive

Even though we have access to the google documentation about this topic [here](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploy-flex-jar), I’ve thought hard to follow all the instructions once we need to have Eclipse installed. To make matters worse, I haven’t found anything on the internet that could help me to deploy an .war file using an App Engine of Google Cloud Computing (GCP).

**Context**

In my specific case, I coded an application using Bazel + Guice ([bazel-guice-app](https://github.com/vitoresende/bazel-guice-app)) and I didn’t find any easy tutorial explaining how to deploy it without installing anything (of course, we need to install GCP SDK).

**Goal**

Deploy an application in App Engine using .war/.jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as did Google tutorial, to deploy a pre-existing WAR or runnable JAR file we need to start setting up an app.yaml file with flexible environment, java runtime and with our jar/war file:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
handlers:
  - url: /.*
  script: <file_name>.war
```

*N.B.: it assumes your app.yaml file is located in the same folder of your jar/war file.*

Once we have our .yaml file we can deploy our application running the following gcloud command (you must have GCP SDK installed or use GCP cloud shell):

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

Simple as you can see, we just need to wait for the deploy process to finish.